# How to start different actions on server with two buttons on website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, pug

Please think about: I'm a beginner and try to learn progamming with javascript.

My goal: I have two buttons on a website. Each of both has to start his own function on the server.

Thanks to various tutorials I manage to trigger an action on the server. But now I have to distinguish two buttons for different server actions.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser());

var tweetText = 'A lot of tweet text...';
var user = 'Lutz';
var account = '@name';
var relevance = 0;
var tweetID_str = 0;
var RTs = 0;


//Send data from client/browser to server
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('works');
    console.log(req.body);    
});

//Send data from server to client
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  relevance = relevance + 1;
  tweetID_str = tweetID_str + 2;
  RTs = RTs +3;

  console.log('relevance: '+relevance+' userbytwo: '+tweetID_str);
  res.render('index', { tweetText: 'Text: '+tweetText, account: '@User: '+account, user: 'User: '+user, relevance: 'RT per follower: '+relevance, tweetID_str: 'ID_str: '+tweetID_str, RTs: 'RTs: '+RTs });
 /* updated this line */
});

app.listen(3000);
```

index.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="de")
  head

  body
    div 
      div!= tweetText
      div!= account
    div
      div!= user
      div!= relevance
      div!= tweetID_str
      div!= RTs

form(method='post')
  div
    input(type='submit', id='good', value='good')
    input(type='submit', id='bad', value='bad')
<!--    input(type='text', name='username') -->
```

I guess, I have to parse the website action. Depending on the result the server starts his action. I'm right or wrong? And what do I have to do, that my code works?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably capture the id of the button after click and then call the necessary action based on the id received using jquery. For example you could do something like:

```
$('#good').click(function(){
 // Do the action on server that you want to do on click of good button.
});


$('#bad').click(function(){
 // Do the action on server that you want to do on click of bad button.
});
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted ? Let me know your exact needs for more help.

### You can use JQuery AJAX call to invoke a method as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#good').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/home"
        }).then(function(data) {
           alert(data); // Do whatever you want to do with response.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Naresh, for your fast answer. This way I have seen two. But unfortunately I don't understand how it works. Up to now I didn't write the depending server functions. Let's say $('#good').click(function(){ } has to start function goodTweets() and $('#bad').click(function(){ } has to start function badTweets() on server side. How should it be implemented and what means $ ?

Comment: $ is for jQuery selector. You will have to include a jquery library on your page. try this link to see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/Q8KVC/

Comment: Thank for the example. It calls a css on the same site. I need to start functions on the server. I have tryed it this was without succes:

$('#good').click(function(){
  $.post('/good')
});

Comment: Please check my comment "text in bold in old answer" I have added a code sample. OR you can try searching google about how to do a ajax post request using jquery.